# SP2013: Display templates with pictures and after select a picture show info (title, description) in another div?

Tags: 2013, display-template

I am using SharePoint 2013. I have a list with 4 columns (title, description, picture, url). I would like to create a search content webpart which is showing a table with the latest 6 items from this list. I have implement the webpart and the query. The data is available now.

Now I just would like to design the layout to something like this.[image]

You will see 4 pictures on the left and 2 on the right. In the middle is some block with the information (title and description) of the selected picture.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Maybe this picture grid with Bootstrap 3 can help you: http://www.bootply.com/70929

Comment: Isn't that easy with a Visual Web Part..? Why would you have a display template for this?

Comment: No, I would like the search content webpart to make the webpart custimezable like search query, filter, sorting etc. I think the best way is to build a display template. I have already cloned the OOTB one.